# ThreadLocal initialValue() called multiple times per thread. why?

Tags: java, thread-local

We see an issue due to ThreadLocal's initialValue() being called multiple times.

```
private static class MonMetricsTLS extends ThreadLocal<IMonitor> {
    public MonMetricsTLS(MetricConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected IMonitor initialValue() {
            IMonitor mon = new MonitorImpl(config);
            timer.schedule(new SenderTimerTask(mon), config.senderPeriodMs(), config.senderPeriodMs());
            return mon;
    }
}
```

Between first and second calls timer can go bad and we get illegalstateexception in schedule().

Why is it getting called multiple times per thread?

Comment: Can you show us how you use it?

Comment: is this actual code ? Why do you have redundant local `Timer` in constructor ? and where do you initialize `this.timer` ?

Comment: otherwise the timer you refer to in `initialValue()` must be declared static in your outer class. Is it the case ?

Comment: timer in constr is not redundant - it gets used in initialvalue

Comment: We have no idea where that call is being used, so we don't know what is calling the methods it's overriding. Please show us where and how you use that class

Comment: The question is about initialValue() behaviour of ThreadLocal. This is pretty much the usage. Threads call get() and timer starts running - one per thread.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are using the same `Timer` object in more than one thread. You should move the `new Timer()` into `initialValue()`. Only then you can be sure to have a unique `Timer` object per thread. And guessing from your code, `config` is immutable so you can pass `this` into the timer. You then only create one MonMetrics and reuse it in all threads.

Comment: But why you would want a new Timer per thread is another question. Rather wasteful I would have thought.

Comment: I am not reusing timer between threads. @EJP - yes we have removed it now. It was an old code base.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like java thread local doesn't guarantee initialValue() will be called exactly once! 
So it is best to assume it can be called any number of times.

Comment: The whole point of `initialValue()` is to be called many times, at least once per thread. But it will also not be called more than once per thread. ThreadLocal takes care of storing any provided intial value in an internal map such that any further access to the value is honored from the map instead of from initial value.

Comment: if it is "initialValue" for a thread local, it should be called just once per thread at least going by function name. In particular the guarantee you mention about "not called more than once" is not there.